# Error when using naming convention in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am working on this project using Zurb Foundation framework and it runs on Gulp. Basically what Gulp does is turn sass into css, compress, concatenate, etc. It runs perfect and it does what it’s suppose to do, UNTIL I try to change the name of the `dist` folder, where everything is built for production. The name I want to use is `name-html5`. The `-html5` is a naming convention of **3dCart**, so it needs the `-html5` in the name of the folder. In `gulpfile.babel.js` I have:

```
// Delete the "dist" folder
// This happens every time a build starts
function clean(done) {
  rimraf(PATHS.dist, done);
}
```

If I substitute the `dist` for `name-html5` I get a build error: `ReferenceError: html5 is not defined` because of the `-` in front of it. It just won’t take `(PATHS.name-html5, done)`.

Also, I changed the name in `config.yml` file:

```
# Gulp will reference these paths when it copies files
PATHS:
  # Path to dist folder
  dist: "dist"
```

but it didn't fix the issue. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a `name-html5` property name, try taking out the hyphen. It can stay in the value.

```
# Gulp will reference these paths when it copies files
PATHS:
  # Path to dist folder
  dist: "dist"
  nameHtml5: "name-html5"
```

Then reference it as `PATHS.nameHtml5`

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. Just one more thing. When I do any changes a `dist` folder is being still generated. There is no reference of it in `gulp file.babel.js` and `config.yml`. In fact, I did a search in the solution and there is no `dist` anywhere.

Comment: A lot of things can cause a folder to be generated, including npm packages that your search may not be looking in.  I recommend creating a separate question for that.