# After renaming the `dist`directory in Gulp is still generating it

Tags: npm, gulp

I am working on a project using the Zurb Foundation framework and it runs on Gulp.

The issue I am having is that I renamed the folder `dist` (where everything is built for production) to something else and when I run `npm run build` is generating both, the directory with the `new-name` and `dist`.

I already checked the `gulpfile.babel.js` and `config.yml` and there are no instances of `dist`. You can take a look to an issue **[I posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279551/error-when-using-naming-convention-in-gulp/50279624?noredirect=1#comment87577282_50279624)**.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I deleted a couple of node modules I didn't need but forgot to deleted some references to them. After deleting them the `dist` is not being generated. Case solved.